# Can I request part of a JSON string? Or decode only specific parts to speed up the process?

Tags: php, json

I've got a very slow performing page, because it's loaded down by JSON requests.

So I was wondering how I can speed the whole thing up. Can I request only part of the string? Considering all I'm using from the following one is the "cast" array, it's a waste to have to get all of it.

The following code has to run for every movie listed on my page, which at the moment is 20. But before just cutting the number of movies down, I was wondering how I could speed this part up, which is the proper problem.

Here's the code I've got that slows the page down, as it has to run 20 times.

```
$films_result = $tmdb->getMovie($film->id);
$films = json_decode($films_result);
foreach ($films as $film) {
 foreach ($film->cast as $cast) {
  if ($cast->job == 'Actor') {
   echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . '</a> ';
   $num_actors++;
   if ($num_actors == 5)
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

I've had a look around, but I don't know what I'm looking for. I'm very very much a beginner at this. So please could any solutions not involve any other technologies, just PHP please.

Comment: What's the JSON format (not the whole thing, just the basics)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, sorry? Here's an example of a whole string if that helps - http://getfilm.co.uk/testing/movie_example.php

Comment: Are you sure it's the JSON parsing and not the part where you fetch the data from remote resource? If you can't cache anything then there's no much help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API gets 0 of 100 points in google page speed because the compression is disabled.
Your JSON output will load 95% faster with compression enabled.

It might be hard to fix if you are not in control of the server but here's a link how to fix it anyways.

[Minimize payload](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression)

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a cron job that grabs all the JSON every X minutes behind the scenes (that way it doesn't matter how slow it is), then parse it and store it in a database. Then each time you load the PHP page you've shown above, just grab the cached data from the database and output that.

Comment: Can't cache or store anything unfortunately. It's not allowed in the api agreement for the database I'm pulling this from.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to parse a lot of JSON x 20 in less than a second. How do you know that the JSON is the bottle neck? There's probably some other problem. How quickly is the data retrieved from the database?

Comment: Well I don't really, that was an assumption. How can I check the speed of retrieval?

Comment: use some timing statements before and after the data is retrieved from the database and subtract the values to get the difference. not sure how you'd do this in PHP but it's a pretty basic thing to do in any language; i hack java, not php

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming the JSON decoding is the cause of the slowness: I'd bet (a small amount of) money on the API response time being the sink, not the parsing.

Assuming it IS need the parsing, you're really hoping for a streaming parser of some kind: in Java land there is json-simple (see http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_5_-_Stoppable_SAX-like_content_handler) which lets you use a handler and track the state yourself so you only bother keeping the bits you care about. Unfortunately PHP doesn't really expose the parser callbacks that `json_decode` uses, and none of the older JSON encoders/decoders are really supported any more (not that any of them exposed callbacks to user code anyway).

You might consider dumping the JSON out to the client and parsing it there instead, if it is really a constraint.